# Is $ \sup\{|a|^4+|a\overline{b}|^2;\;(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2\;\;\hbox{and}\;|a|^2+|b|^2=1\}<1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

> I want to compute the following supremum of at least prove that
> $$
> \sup\left\{|a|^4+|a\overline{b}|^2;\;(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2\;\;\hbox{and}\;|a|^2+|b|^2=1\right\}<1.$$

I used the following inequalities
$$|a\overline{b}|\leq \frac{1}{2}(|a|^2+|b|^2)\text{ and } |a|^2\leq |a|^2+|b|^2.$$
I get
$$|a|^4+|a\overline{b}|^2\leq \frac{5}{4},$$
for every $(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$. So
$$
\sup\left\{|a|^4+|a\overline{b}|^2;\;(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2\;\;\hbox{and}\;|a|^2+|b|^2=1\right\}\leq \frac{5}{4}.$$
But this not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

$$|a|^4+|a\overline{b}|^2= \vert a \vert^4 + \vert a \vert^2 \vert b\vert^2= \vert a \vert^4 + \vert a \vert^2( 1- \vert a \vert^2)=\vert a \vert^2 \le 1$$

for all $a,b$ such that $\vert a \vert^2+ \vert b\vert^2=1$.

Comment: Thank you but please I think $$\vert a \vert^4 + \vert a \vert^2( 1- \vert a \vert^2)=\vert a \vert^2$$ Why this is equals to $1$?

Comment: Sure you're right! I fixed my mistake.

Comment: thanks a lot but my goal is to prove that sup is strictly less than 1

Comment: This is wrong. Take $a=1$ and $b=0$ for example.

Comment: Thanks. So it is equal to $1$

Comment: Yes this is right.